# Can the generators of a Lie group furnish its adjoint representation?

Tags: operators, gauge-theory, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

For generators of the Lie group under an arbitrary representation: $[T^a,T^b]=if^{abc}T^c$

$[T_A^c]^{ab}=-if^{cab}$ is the generator of the adjoint representation.

Is $\ \  e^{i\theta^d T^d}T^ae^{-i\theta^e T^e}=[e^{-i\theta^cT_{A}^{c}}]^{ab}T^b\ \ $ correct to all orders? How to prove it?

The formula is obviously true at the first order. I also checked second order, which is still true. So it's likely to be correct to all orders. A proof to all orders is desired.

Repeated index are summed over.

Comment: It is indeed correct. Use the BCH formula to prove this. Hint: $[ T^a , T^b ] = - (T^a_A)^{bc} T^c$

Comment: @Prahar Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The BCH formula is a bit more general. For your problem, you just need the formula:
$$
\exp\text{ad}_x = \text{Ad}_{e^x}
$$
or more explicitly:
$$
\begin{align}
\exp([x,.])y &:= y+[x,y]+\frac12[x,[x,y]] +... \\
&={e^x}ye^{-x}
\end{align}
$$
The usual way to prove this is to solve the equation:
$$
\dot y = [x,y]
$$
It is a linear equation, so by definition of the matrix exponential:
$$
y(t) = \exp(t[x,.])y(0)
$$
On the other hand, you can check directly that:
$$
y(t) = e^{tx}y(0)e^{-tx}
$$
is the solution given the initial condition $y(0)$. By setting $t=1$, you can conclude.

Btw, you can generalise this beyond matrix Lie groups and its corresponding Lie algebra. You can view this as the definition of the exponential map from the Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ to the Lie group $G$.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

1. Let $G$ be a [Lie group](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group) with [Lie algebra](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra) $\mathfrak{g}\simeq\mathrm{T}_eG$.
   The Lie algebra has a natural *real* vector space structure.
2. The [adjoint representation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation) is a natural action of the group $G$ on the vector space $V=\mathfrak{g}$ given by
   $$\mathrm{Ad}:G\longrightarrow\mathrm{GL}(\mathfrak{g}),\quad g\mapsto\mathrm{Ad}_g \tag{A}\label{A}$$
   where
   $$\mathrm{Ad}_g:\mathfrak{g}\longrightarrow\mathfrak{g},\quad X\mapsto gXg^{-1}.$$
   Note that for a matrix Lie group this is well defined, via the ordinary matrix product; otherwise, the notation above is understood in terms of [pushforwards](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_(differential)) via left and right translations by $G$.
3. Being a Lie group homomorphism, \eqref{A} is differentiable and the differential is the Lie algebra homomorphism
   $$\mathrm{ad}:\mathfrak{g}\longrightarrow\mathfrak{gl}(\mathfrak{g}),\quad X\to \mathrm{ad}_X:=[X,.]\tag{B}\label{B}.$$
4. For the [exponential map](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_(Lie_theory)) the following [commutative diagram](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_diagram) holds,
   [image]
   meaning that
   $$\exp(\mathrm{ad}_X)=\mathrm{Ad}_{\exp X}\tag{C}\label{C}.$$
   which is the sought after relation.
   Note that I'm using the mathematicians' convention for the exponential map, as opposed to the physicists' convention OP is using.
5. To reconcile with OP's notation, let me write \eqref{C} in a similar fashion. Let $\{T^a\}_{a=1}^{\dim G}$ be a basis of the algebra. Then define the notation
   $$T_A^b:=\mathrm{ad}_{T^b}.$$
   Now, expand $$X=\theta^b T^b\implies \mathrm{ad}_X=\sum_b\theta^b\mathrm{ad}_{T_b}=\theta^bT^b_A$$
   Finally, consider the action of the operator \eqref{C} on a basis element $T^a$ of $V=\mathfrak{g}$
   $$\exp(\theta^bT_A^b)(T^a)=\mathrm{Ad}_{\exp(\theta^bT^b)}(T_a)=\exp(\theta^bT^b)T^a\exp(-\theta^bT^b),$$
   which written in index notation is precisely OP's equation.